# Bind label text to complex property

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, data-binding

I have a label control in WPF

```
<Label
    Name="lblEventID" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="False">
    <Label.Content>
        <AccessText Text="{Binding Path= NoteText}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" FontFamily="Impact"></AccessText>
    </Label.Content>
    <Label.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="10" Opacity=".5"></DropShadowEffect>
    </Label.Effect>
</Label>
```

And this code works fine. Now I have a new object called Note, and a property of Note is NoteText. So now my class contains a Note Object, with the property of NoteText. My question is how do I bind the property of this object to the label. I thought it would be something like:

```
<Label
    Name="lblEventID" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="False">
    <Label.Content>
        <AccessText ***Text="{Binding Path= ActiveNote.NoteText}"*** TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" FontFamily="Impact"></AccessText>
    </Label.Content>
    <Label.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="10" Opacity=".5"></DropShadowEffect>
    </Label.Effect>
</Label>
```

Comment: So, is it not working? Because unless you are not setting DataContext property it should work: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html

Comment: should the data context be this or this.ActiveNote or ActiveNote or...

Comment: If you are setting context of the whole Window to itself, then it should be this (on the code behind). If you have a view-model class, then it should be that class instance.

Comment: `I thought it would be something like...` It is exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DataContext for this page(or Window) is set to the codebehind using:
1. In the constructor : `this.DataContext=this`
2. In the Xaml using `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

then to bind to The NoteText property of the Note Object use simply :

```
Text="{Binding Path= Note.NoteText}
```